Description of the generalized permutahedron
According to Postnikov, we know that the generalized permutahedron are describe as "polytopes obtained by moving vertices of the usual permutohedron so that directions of all edges are preserved" and this can be described as the convex hull of the $n!$ points $V_w \in \Bbb R^n$, $w \in S_n$, s.t. for all $w \in S_n$ and all adjacent transposition $s_i=(i, i+1)$ we have that
$$v_w - v_{ws_i}=k_{w, i} \cdot(e_{w(i)}-e_{w(i+1)}) \quad \text{for some } k_{w, i} \in \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$$
Now, recall that a facet of a polytope $P$ is a face $F$ that satisfies that $\dim(F)=\dim(P)-1$, we will say that each generalized permutohedron is obtained by parallel translation of the facets of a usual permutohedron, so all generalized permutohedron is parameterized by colections $\{Z_{I} \}$, $Z_I \in \Bbb R$ and $I \subseteq \{1, \dots,n \}$
This whole idea is summarized by considering that every generalized permutahedron is defined by the inequalities
$$P_n ^Z(\{Z_{I} \})=\{(t_1, \dots, t_n) \in \Bbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^n t_i=Z_{[n]}, \sum_{i \in I} t_i \geq Z_{I} \quad \text{for all } I \subseteq  \{1, \dots,n \} \}$$
I have tried to think how this last equality summarizes the fact that it is a parallel translation of the facets of the usual permutahedron, I do not understand very well how to visualize such parallel translations, is it possible that someone can help me to decipher this last equality from the facets of a polytope, it would be very useful!

It is not clear to me exactly what your question is. In particular, I don't know whether you are struggling to "visualize" things, or whether you are struggling to just understand basic definitions. Visualization in arbitrary dimensions is not easy and I'm not sure I can help with that (of course thinking about dimensions 2 and 3 is a good start). But maybe I can clarify the definitions.
In general a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented by a finite collection of inequalities of the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n \geq b$. This is called the "facet description" of the polytope, because these defining inequalities correspond to facets of the polytope in the sense that the facets are the points where we have equality for one of these inequalities.
(I'm ignoring the fact that our polytope might be not full dimensional, which actually does happen with the permutohedron, but that is not a big issue.)
Parallel translation of a facet corresponding to the inequality $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n \geq b$ then just corresponds to replacing the $b$ on the right-hand side by some $b'$, while keeping the $a_i$'s (which define the normal vector to the facet) the same.
The final thing you need to know to see why generalized permutohedra are given by the $Z_I$ inequalities you wrote down is that the facet description of the usual permutohedron (i.e., the convex hull of all permutations of $(1,2,\ldots,n)$) is given by
$$ \sum_{i \in [n]}x_i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2},  \sum_{i \in I}x_i \geq \frac{\#I(\#I+1)}{2} \textrm{ for all $\varnothing\neq I\subsetneq[n]$}, $$
so that indeed the normals to these facets are what you wrote.
But a word of warning: not every collection of $Z_I$'s defines a generalized permutohedron. This is because we are only allowed to translate the facets so far: we can slide a facet up to the point that some vertices collide and become identified, but we cannot slide it "past" this point. The allowable collections of $Z_I$'s form the "deformation cone" of the permutohedron.
One more suggestion. I guess you are reading Postnikov's first paper on generalized permutohedra, Permutohedra, associahedra, and beyond. You might also want to check out the follow up paper Faces of Generalized Permutohedra by Postinkov, Reiner, and Williams. Especially worth reading is its Appendix, which compares various kinds of deformation (e.g. vertex versus facet), because that might be what's tripping you up. Postinkov originally defined generalized permutohedra in terms of vertex deformations but the facet deformation description is the more popular one now.

Thank you for your description, it is what I was looking for and it has been very useful.

Hey there! I'm back on this post because I'm wondering: where does the name "facet description" come from? I know that in Ziegler's book Lectures on Polytopes, this description using inequalities appears, but it's not explicitly referred to by that name. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at this message.

The facets of the polytope are the faces of highest dimension. This is terminology used more generally for complexes where we have some notion of face like simplicial complexes, CW complexes, etc. In the case of convex polytopes, the defining inequalities exactly correspond to the facets of the polytope (if it is full dimensional in its ambient space, at least).
